# Connection uri of local MQTT broker

Tags: networking, mqtt, mosquitto

I currently have two MQTT brokers both working perfectly fine. One of them is a **Raspberry Pi** on my **local** network. The other one is a **remote** broker hosted on [CloudMQTT](http://cloudmqtt.com).

The goal is to sync both brokers with each other. The easy solution for this, of course, is a bridge, but I'm having some trouble getting a proper bridge setup.

As you can see in the image below, when I try to setup a bridge on [CloudMQTT](http://cloudmqtt.com), it asks for a **'Connection uri'**. For a remote broker, this would be `mqtt://username:password@m20.cloudmqtt.com:1883`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this for a local broker. [image]

As far as I know, you can only connect to your local network when you have a static IP and the ports forwarded to the Raspberry Pi, so how would I be able to get around this? The two brokers need to keep a **permanent TCP** connection open, but the remote broker can't open it himself. Wouldn't it be possible for the local broker to open this connection? If so, how would I get the two brokers to sync?

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot for your help in advance!

**Edit:**

This is my full /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf file:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d


connection CloudMQTT-Bridge

topic # both 2 local/testing remote/testing

bridge_protocol_version mqttv311

address m20:cloudmqtt.com:17001
remote_username jcw******
remote_password p-fO*****
remote_clientid RaspberryPiBroker
```

Comment: You have a `:` instead of a `.` in the address line at the start of the address

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out! I fixed that mistake, but still can't publish or sub to the local broker..

Comment: Check the log for output, those details work fine for for me (expect I get unauthorised for the bridge as I don't have the creds). If you are running as a service you can stop it and run it manually with `mosquitto -c /path/to/config`

Comment: Wow, thanks for this very handy trick to run it manually! This way, I was able to get some feedback where it went wrong. Turned out that the log_dest didn't exist and I had to use username instead of remote_username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create bridges with mosquitto, the "Configuring Bridges" section of the [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) page covers all the options, but the basics you will need are:

```
connection cloudMQ-Bridge
address m20.cloudmqtt.com
remote_username user
remote_password password
remote_clientid clientid
topic # in 2
```

The tricky bit is the topic line at the end which controls how topics are to be mapped between the two brokers. You must be careful not to create loops.

In the example all topics are mapped in from the remote broker to the local broker at QOS 2 without any topic remapping. Please read the section of manual about topic mapping closely as it is easy to make mistakes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your example, but I'm experiencing a weird issue. When I edit the conf and restart mosquitto, I can't subscribe or publish to the local broker. For some reason, I always get 'Error: Connection refused'. What would be the cause of this?

Comment: That's most likely going to be either wrong username/password or address/port for the remote connection

Comment: That makes sense! I tried to connect to CloudMQTT from an Arduino and it didn't work, so here I'm probably experiencing the same issue. One weird thing is that it does work when just publishing from Terminal to CloudMQTT..

Comment: try adding `bridge_protocol_version` with a value of `mqttv311`

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately. So you think because Mosquitto can't connect to CloudMQTT, I can't even sub to the local broker? MQTT is pretty hard to troubleshoot..

Comment: Edit the original question to include your whole mosquitto.conf